# Like statement for datetime in SQL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I try to do a filter for SQL search. I have a database with columns id,remarks and date. Date column datatype is datetime. What i want to do is using LIKE statement to filter the search. Its like  `where date like '%2016%'`. I want data from the year 2016 only. I try to use contains. but no success

```
Dim Query = From apt In dbb.apt
Where apt.date.Contains("2016")
Select apt.id, apt.remarks, apt.date
```

Comment: apt.date is a datetime. I will convert the date into string in order to store it as JSON format. Now I only want to do a filter search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below to get year value from your date filed.

```
Year(data_column)
```

Comment: where should i put the value (2016)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Dim Query = From apt In dbb.apt
Where apt.date.Year.CompareTo("2016")
Select apt.id, apt.remarks, apt.date
```

Comment: In place of  "Where apt.date.Year.CompareTo("2016")". you can also try Where apt.date.Year("2016") as @balaji told